# Baby bottle gourd falling off

Tags: vegetables, organic, gourds

Why baby bottle gourd is falling off from bottle gourd plant?

The green color baby bottle gourd turns yellow from green color and then falls off. Only 1% success I have. There are lots of flowers turns into baby bottle gourds

What could be the reason? And how to stop this?
[image]

Comment: A better picture?

Comment: Different squash, likely same problem: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/27532/6806